# $.post issue after deploying code to tomcat

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, tomcat, tomcat6

I am using below code that reads file name from html FILE tag and send it to ReadExcel.jsp. Once the post message is complete, it will reload the home.jsp page. ReadExcel.jsp reads the excel file and saves the data to database. Home.Jsp reads the same excel information from database and display it in grid.

The above procedure works fine as long as I run the file from Eclipse on my system. Once I deploy the file on to Tomcat on my Test server, it is not sending the post values to ReadExcel.jsp. Below is the jquery code that sends post values to ReadExcel.jsp.  Any help?

```
   $("#fileupload").change(function() {
   if($("#fileupload").val().length > 0) {    

       $.post("ReadExcel.jsp", {
            filename: $("#fileupload").val(), 
            processId: <%=processId%>

       },function(data){

           location.reload(window.location.replace=("home.jsp?procid="+<%=processId%>)); 

       });
       }

});
```

Is there any way that I can re-write this in Ajax if no solution found? I know Javascript and trying to implement it in Javascript. ..

Comment: What is the page URL after deployment?

Comment: https://serverNameOR_IPAddress/BulkAccess/home.jsp

Comment: Like monotheist suggests probably mapping issues or maybe even a cross-origin issue. You can check the console for error messages. If you use chrome or safari you can check the response in the network tab in the developpertools.

Comment: Now, I tried Developer Toolbar with Firefox and got below error after the post message. Does this indicate any syntax wrong?             [17:33:33.879] Error: Permission denied to shadow native property @ https://ServerName/BulkAccess/home.jsp:295

Comment: If it is an issue with mapping, I think it should also not work on Eclipse. Correct me if I am wrong.. Thank you.